# Google Sign-In doesn't always work

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-signin

I'm implementing server side flow of Google Sign-in described here:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow

My problem is, that **on some computers, in some browsers, it doesn't work**.

- First computer, in Google Chrome 44.0.2403.157 m - works
- First computer, Microsoft Edge 20.10525.0.0 - never works
- First computer, IE 11 - never works
- Second computer, Google Chrome same version - version from docs (below) works always, implemented on website - worked once, doesn't anymore

Here is a plunker with the code I was testing. Most of it is copied from [the docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow).

Expected behavior for the code: after signing in, under button should appear "result in console" and there should be an object with the *one time code* in javascript console. **When it doesn't work, the callback doesn't get called and there's no change on the website.** I couldn't get it to produce any error message.

http://plnkr.co/s7EJbkEHL6ubnSR7DUmw

```
<!-- The top of file index.html -->
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
<head>
  <!-- BEGIN Pre-requisites -->
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js?onload=start" async defer>
  </script>
  <!-- END Pre-requisites -->

  <!-- Continuing the <head> section -->
  <script>
    function start() {
      gapi.load('auth2', function() {
        auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
          client_id: '655082111777-8dlr2thnsn9a1v74f55ku2gs1gjjcpaj.apps.googleusercontent.com',
          // Scopes to request in addition to 'profile' and 'email'
          //scope: 'additional_scope'
        });
      });
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Add where you want your sign-in button to render -->
    <!-- Use an image that follows the branding guidelines in a real app -->
    <button id="signinButton">Sign in with Google</button>
    <script>
      $('#signinButton').click(function() {
        // signInCallback defined in step 6.
        auth2.grantOfflineAccess({'redirect_uri': 'postmessage'}).then(signInCallback);
      });
    </script>
    <div id="result"></div>
<!-- Last part of BODY element in file index.html -->
<script>
function signInCallback(authResult) {
    $('#result').append("result in console");
    console.log(authResult);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please provide any advice on how to get it to work always and everywhere.